# Using QueryDslRepositorySupport in combination with interface repositories

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

since I didn't get a reply on the spring forum I'll give it a try here.

Is there a way to have a common interface repository which is extended by interfaces the following way:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CommonRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {
 T getById(final long id);
}

@Repository
public interface ConcreteRepository extends CommonRepository<ConcreteEntity> {
  List<ConcreteEntity> getByNameAndAddress(final String name, final String address);
}

public class ConcreteRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements ConcreteRepository {

    private BooleanExpression nameEquals(final QConcreteEntity entity, final String name) {
        return entity.eq(name);
    }

    public List<ConcreteEntity> getByNameAndAddress(final String name, final String address) {
        QConcreteEntity entity = QConcreteEntity.concreteEntity;
        return from(entity).where(entity.name.eq(name).and(entity.address.eq(address))).list(entity);
    }
}
```

The problem with the implementation is that I have to implement `getById(final long id)`
in each concrete class. I don't want to do that. Normally, spring data automatically knows about each entity. Also I want to have the functionality of `QueryDslRepositorySupport`.
In my example it normally generates something like:

```
select .. from concreteentity en where en.id = ...
```

Is there a way to solve it? I already stumbled upon
[Spring Jpa adding custom functionality to all repositories and at the same time other custom funcs to a single repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765684/spring-jpa-adding-custom-functionality-to-all-repositories-and-at-the-same-time)

and

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations

but I don't think these solutions are helpful and I don't entirely understand how I can use them to solve the problem.

Thanks,

Christian

Comment: Could you fix the links at the end of your question?

Comment: @TimoWestkämper: fixed it, sorry.

Comment: I'd like to hear from an expert on this too. I think the simple answer would be that we'd need to create a separate querydsl repository for the entity, separate from the standard repository, but that seems lame

Comment: I just checked, and Spring Roo's approach is indeed to have to repos. They generate a EntityRepo and a EntityCustomRepo, the custom one being the one with the querydsl support-

Answer (score 1):

One way to create a generic getById under `QuerydslRepositorySupport` is like this

```
T getById(long id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(getBuilder().getType(), id)
}
```